# Soap String Can not connect to server

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, soap-client, soapserver

Below my soap information.

```
 NAMESPACE = "http://wm.tren.com/";
 URL = "http://wmc.com:80/tren/TrenService";
 SOAP_ACTION = "http://wm.tren.com/gettest";
 METHOD = "gettest";
```

Im using soap server .But I can not connect the server with my below soapstring.I got fault code. Anyone can help me?

```
   NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:

@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"

"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:TrenService=\"http://wm.tren.com/\" xsl:version=\"1.0\">\n"

"<soap:Body>\n"

    "<gettest xsi:type=\"TrenService:gettest/\">\n"

"<cdOr>%@</cdOr>\n"

    "<cdDest>%@</cdDest>\n"

    "<date>%@</date>\n"

    "</gettest>\n"

"</soap:Body>\n"

"</soap:Envelope>\n", @"01005",@"01007",@"2013-10-22"

];
```

Here is the error message:

```
version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post the error message as well please

Comment: sure
 ========
version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
==== this is the error messgae

Comment: can you add the error message to the question so that it is more readable for people thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer. Soap string should be written with the extentions. With SoapUI i have checked and i have seen these types. Thanks.